# Does this random vector follow a multinomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

Suppose a sample $X_1, X_2, ...$ follows a Binomial distribution with parameters $m \in \mathbb N$ and $\pi \in (0, 1)$. Denote
\begin{equation}
    Z_k := \sum_i I(X_i = k) \quad \text{for} \quad k = 0, 1, \ldots, m,
\end{equation}

where $I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function.

This particular problem concerns the case of missing data for $Z_0$. We are given that $\sum_{k=1}^m Z_k =: n$. Moreover, $Z_0 + n$ follows a negative binomial distribution with parameters $r = n$ and 
\begin{equation}
    \theta = \mathbb P (X_i \geqslant 1) = 1 - (1 - p)^m.
\end{equation}

The question is, what is the joint distribution of $Z_0, \ldots, Z_m$, i.e. what is 
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb P (Z_0 = z_0, \ldots, Z_6 = z_6).
\end{equation}

Normally I would say the distribution is Multinomial with class probabilities
\begin{equation}
    \pi_k = \mathbb P (X_i = k) \quad \text{for} \quad k = 0, \ldots, m,
\end{equation}

but the size parameter cannot be $n + Z_0$. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!